# MYSQL - Error Code :- 1241 "Operand should contain 1 column(s) "

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a project.
I have the following query

```
select sid, reading, (
    select customer_id as cid, sub_location_id as location_id
    from customer_information  where sub_location_id = 1)
    from customer_consumption 
where customer_consumption.customer_id = customer_information.customer_id 
and month(bill_date) = month(now())
```

#### help out of this

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want an explicit join:

```
select cc.sid, cc.reading, 
       ci.customer_id as cid, ci.sub_location_id as location_id
from customer_consumption cc join
     customer_information ci
     on cc.customer_id = ci.customer_id 
where month(bill_date) = month(now()) and ci.sub_location_id = 1;
```

Your original syntax is highly unorthodox.  You seem to need to learn more about how to use SQL.

Comment: thanks, it works, and you are right, I need to work more on sql, thanks again :)